# Email.less won't compile

Tags: email, email-templates, less-css, less

I tried to customize my emails with the _email-extend.less in my theme.
But no matter what I try to do at the end Magento only compiles the email-inline.css instead of the email.css.
I also tried to copy the _email.less in my theme and changed some selectors but again ... nohting changed.

So what files do I need to create my own email.css?

Comment: Did you solve this yet?